# what is better to train your own model for sentiment analysis or to use pre trained model like vader and textblob?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis, pre-trained-model

I have python script that trained a dataset for sentiment analysis and create a model using  **logisticRegression** model with **tfidf** , **cross validation** , **bigram** and **GridSearchCV**. With performing the pre-process phase for the text.

And i tried to use pre trained model like **VaderSentiment** in order to compare between the 2 models.

the result on real data was :

- logisticRegression accuracy: 64.2%
- VaderSentiment accuracy:     85.7%

so where is the error in my trained model ? or its better to use the vaderSentiment for twitter sentiment analysis?

Note that in my trained result i got :

```
Accuracy: 91.482%
Best parameters set found on development set:

{'bow__ngram_range': (1, 2), 'tfidf__use_idf': True}

Optimized model achieved an ROC of:  0.9998
```

## LR model:

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    from sklearn import metrics
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
    from sklearn import model_selection
    
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix,accuracy_score
    
    cross_val = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42)
    # create pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('bow', CountVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii',
                                stop_words=['english'],# add or delete arabic based on the content of the tested df 
                                lowercase=True)),  # strings to token integer counts
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),  # integer counts to weighted TF-IDF scores
        ('classifier', LogisticRegression(C=15.075475376884423,penalty="l2")),  # train on TF-IDF vectors w/ Naive Bayes classifier
    ])
    
    # this is where we define the values for GridSearchCV to iterate over
    parameters = {'bow__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],
                  'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
                    
                 }
    
    
    
    clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters, cv=cross_val, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1, scoring= 'roc_auc')
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    
test_twtr_preds = LR_Model.predict(test_twtr['processed_TEXT'])
```

## VaderSentiment:

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

def print_sentiment_scores(text):
    snt = analyser.polarity_scores(text)  #Calling the polarity analyzer
    if snt["compound"] >= 0.05:
        snt = "positive"
    elif snt["compound"] > -0.05 and snt["compound"] < 0.05:
        snt="neutral"
    elif snt["compound"] <=0.05: 
        snt="Negative"
    return snt
def_test_twtr_preds["Vader_Process"]=def_test_twtr_preds["processed_TEXT"].apply(print_sentiment_scores)
```

Comment: I think it depends on the use case and its requirements. Maybe you can look at the library function in context and refine it to your specific needs. Then test the refined function, if it performs better then your initial assumption stands true else not.

Answer (score 0):

A very useful element in evaluating the precision of any system is knowing the size of the set. An accuracy of 70% over 2000 or 3000 tweets is not the same as over 50. So never forget to say what the size of the data is.

On the other hand, you cannot expect both algorithms to give similar results. Your algorithm is part of the **probabilistic classifiers**, while Vader is rule-based and **lexicon-based**. That's the fundamental difference, so they will never give similar, much less identical results.

If you want to increase the precision of your algorithm, you must have very well classified **bags of words**. Generally these bags are prepared by developers without deep knowledge of the language or the cultural factors that influence the use of words. I use a simple classifier based on statistical methods (without machine learning) and I have obtained an accuracy of up to 87% in a set of 3000 tweets. The difference is huge considering that my algorithm runs in less than a minute and requires **no training**.

So your algorithm is not necessarily wrong, but you cannot compare systems based on different procedures and on different data sets.

Recommendation: Give preference to what offers you the best precision. But if you want to improve your method, start by **raising the precision of your word bags**. There is the key.